# Cryptography not installing

Tags: python, cryptography

I've been trying to install cryptography for a while and I keep receiving the same error. I have installed Rust through Rustup and I am using the latest version of Rust. I  am also not very savvy when it comes to installations so a basic explanation would be helpful if you can. Thanks.

= note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'python3.lib'

error: could not compile `cryptography-rust` due to previous error

` error: cargo failed with code: 101

```
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

Comment: Have you tried using `pip3`? Because it seems you get an error code for Python 3...

Comment: I tried to go through pip3 but it also brought the same errors.